# Benefits of SessionLocator in XMemcached Replication

Tags: java, xmemcached

In my Java app we have used Memcached to set data and get the same data later in the process. 
Later repatch has been applied to Memcached as an new instance of memcache has been introduced, which actually replicate the keys between memcached1 and memcahced2 instances.
So,All the keys in Memcached Instance1 is replicated in to Memcahced Instacne 2.
To make sure nothing was wrong with the SETs, I manually confirmed the data was added to both the Memcached instances.

**My Configurations:
- Xmemcached (1.3.5) with repach (for replication purpose)**

What would be the best strategy to share data between 2 memcache instances equally ? Is there a configuration I'm not using correctly? Should I be using another library?

BTW i have came accross KetamaMemcachedSessionLocator will it act as an load balancer? I mean will it equally divide the key storage between the two memcahced instaces?

Thank you for your help!